# How to use Postgresql's "real" (float4) type in Rails 7.0, instead of the "double precision"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, sqldatatypes, ruby-on-rails-7

I've got a Rails 7.0 app connected to a Postgres Database.

I've got tables with several millions of rows, and each row storing more than 10 columns as float types.

The default way of storing numbers with decimals in Rails is the float type, which corresponds to the float8 type in Postgres (also known as double precision), meaning each value stored as this type is 8bytes of data.

I could save a lot of space by telling Rails, to tell Postgres, to use float4 (real) instead of float8.

Basically cutting in half the size of the biggest table of my database.

The only thing is that i really don't know how to and i don't seem to find any clue about it.

Has someone ever tried to do this ?

Also if that's the case, i take any recommendation regarding the migration itself as i need to switch the existing entries to float4 as well.

Best!

Comment: fyi a table has columns and rows

Comment: Yeah, edited the post, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Did this actually cut your table in half? I'd be surprised. Often ID, row identifiers, indexes and other data would make these savings pretty marginal.

Comment: For 10 columns you could save 40 bytes. For 1 billion records, that would be 37GB in total. Maybe more when you have indexes on these columns as well. Storage is cheap. And it's still a float, with all the issues of a float...  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Agreed @FrankHeikens. But the use case here is pretty special as i want to migrate the database to a DBaaS service. And the application would suffer a lot from a too long downtime due to migrating so I'm actually optimizing every aspect to the maximum so the migration process takes the less time possible. 40gigs of data is already some time saved actually. And i have a few tables that i can lower in size like so !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer by messing around with migrations.

It's as simple as adding a 4 to the float type like so:

```
  def change
    add_column :my_table, :my_column, :float4
  end
```

This results in a 'real' column when checking through psql.